# PHP script to download root folder from EC2?

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

Is it possible to download /var/www/html folder from EC2 using a PHP script? I normally use Filezila (SSH) to download the root directory to  my local machine from EC2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but PHP is definitely not the ideal way to do this.

In order to copy files from the remove EC2 server to your local computer, rsync is a very good choice:

```
rsync -ahv --progress user@your.server:/var/www/html/* /where/you/want/it/on/your/local/computer/
```

This will copy the files through an encrypted tunnel (SSH).
The `--progress` option is useful to keep track of the individual file progress - remove it if you are using a script.